# Should I use figure titles for diagrams on the web?

Tags: technical-writing, marketing, websites

Should I use figure titles for **diagrams** in web content if the diagram already has a caption? Guidance or references are appreciated.

The context is a marketing page whose basic structure is shown in the following image.

[image: Basic layout of the page in question.]

From what I have read about web usability, I'd say the figure title is just another piece of content for readers to scan that is largely redundant with the other content on the page. Any different ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The only reason to use figure titles if they already have a caption is to refer to multiple figures throughout the text, particularly if each one has multiple panels. If so, they should merely say **Fig. 1 A**, for example. Take a look at any scientific article for examples of this, here's [one](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0143047) for starters.

As for your example, I don't think you really need figure titles if there's only one figure per page with the corresponding text right next to it.